# java - why not parse http to Map?

Tags: java, android, json

I am a newbie on Java, and now trying to work on an Android application. I really hate to write so many bean `Class` for every `http` request and response.

oh, my god！！！ so many Bean Class.

In `Js` json is just a `Js` object. In `python`, Json is converted to `Dictionary`.

So in java, why not convert `json` to `Map`? so that we can omit these bean classes. It seems everyone says: use `Gson` and bean class to parse Json, but why?

Question: why Json to Java Bean, not to Map in android?

Comment: No clue what you expect us to answer on such input.

Comment: what is your question? Have you forgotten to ask it?

Comment: Question: why Json to Java Bean, not to Map in android?

Answer (score 1):

There are no benefits from simple conversion json to map. Benefits start to appear when you convert json to static class.
If you hate to create many java beans, look to Kotlin. You may create new bean very easy:

```
data class Student(val age: Int, val name: String, val surname: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you didnt think about ORM advantages =)

Actually you **can** parse Json into Map if you create `Map<String,Object>` instance.

But you can use your Json with same way as Map, so using Map doesnt give you any advantages.

If your project is really small probably there is no big difference between using map or object for getting values. May be map implementation will be even faster.

But imagine you have serious project. You have to get some informations about films for example. And you have good api for it, which gives you list of films in Json. You should save it in your app. 
So your typical actions in that case are:

1. Parse it to `List<Map<String>>`
2. Create database for it.
3. Create tons of methods for inserting/updating/deleting your films in database. Dont forget to convert some non-string values because you have Map which stores only Strings.

In other case with ORM

1. Create class films.
2. Get `List<Films>` directly from Json with something like `GSON` library
3. Store list in database easily just calling `list.get(i).save()` with something like `Sugar ORM`.

Its just saves a time!

Comment: Yeah, I understand, it is useful to work with ORM. But in android develop, most of the time, we get the data from server and then update the UI, so ORM is not the main reason.

Comment: @Leon, as I noticed in that case you can update UI without even casting to Map. You can just get data directly from JsonObject. And it will be completely the same as Map<String,Object>

Comment: Tnx, I know JsonObject. :)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Java is a static typed language, where Python isn't.

You can parse your JSON response to a Map, but you would loose compiler checking. The contents of a map are only runtime, and if you have code that is a nested map your source would quickly become hard to read.

If you create domain objects and have them populated by the JSON the code radiates its intent, and the model behind it.

Changes in the model will reflect throughout the source, which aids people who don't know your source very well, or even yourself when you've not touched it for a while.